# Handle webkit.messageHandler postMessage on Android

Tags: javascript, android, webkit

I tried to execute code in android from the web view through events. So I implemented the good way with a JavascriptInterface, but since I have a iOS Application, I wanted to use the same method. So is this possible to use the message handler on Android (just a simple JS event) rather than the Bridging of the interface ?
I also tried to the other way : Make a bridge on iOS the same way of Android, but it doesn't work with WKWebview (but it's another problem)
Thanks !

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: I am interested in that too.. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Hi, no, I currently use the JavascriptInterface...

Answer (score 4):

*This is not recommended, if you have the option to change your JS-code and add a conditional handler, you should do that instead.*

If you have implemented a handler in iOS using `userContentController` and want to reuse it in Android, you can inject JS to replace the `window.webkit.messageHandlers` property with your android equivalent.

Say this is your swift code:

```swift
webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "iosListener")

func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
  //handle message
}
```

And your JS code:

```js
window.webkit.messageHandlers.iosListener.postMessage("some message")
```

You can reuse it in android/kotlin without changing your JS code like this:

```
inner class MyJsInterface() {

    @JavascriptInterface
    fun postMessage(value: String) {
        //handle message
    }
}

webView.run {
    settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    addJavascriptInterface(MyJsInterface(), "AndroidListener")
    webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
            evaluateJavascript("window.webkit = { messageHandlers: { iosListener: window.AndroidListener} }") {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for this solution! Can you please provide some info about why "This is not recommended"? May be some docs links?

Comment: This injects and evaluates `window.webkit = { messageHandlers: { iosListener: window.AndroidListener} }` on every page load regardless of what page is loaded. 
IMO it's a textbook "hack" and should be avoided. Unless you have full control over the pages you load, it could lead to bugs or pages breaking. You never know if a page uses `window.webkit` for something else.

Comment: its not working for me

Comment: This worked for me on a simple 1 HTML file test webpage, but not with a "real" webpage that is loading separate js files etc